# Is it possible in react to pass state/props value from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a component from where i want to pass data to another component and i have used react-router-dom for routing.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      devices: [],
      data_set: []
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Fragment>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                component={Dashboard} />

              <Route
                exact
                path="/rehab"
                render={(props) =>
                <Rehab {...props}
                  data_val={this.state.data_set}
                  text="Shyam Form" />
                }
              />

              <Route
                exact
                path="/activity"
                render={(props) =>
                <Activity {...props}
                  data_val={this.state.data_set}
                  text="Shyam Activity" />
                }
              />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Fragment>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , wrapper)
`
```

This is my App.js. What I need to access the state variable which I have in my Activity Component inside the Rehab Component.

I am aware of using "windows.entity" as a global store, but that would not be a good practice I assume.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is. Why can't you just pass props? Unrelated, but I find much of your JSX very difficult to read.

Comment: You can use something like React.context to wrap your component hierarchy into a shared context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: If you have two sibling components, one typical solution to data-sharing is to put the state into a component above the two siblings. You can pass a function into one of them for setting the state of the parent, and the other can receive the value from the parent.

Comment: Just use props?

Comment: Small example of sibling components communicating through a parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/mz1yonj468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass down a function from Activity as a prop for Rehab. This function can be called by Rehab in order to perform a state change on Activity, which will in turn update the props of Rehab.

Edit:

Since i see you Rehab is not a child of Activity - You can do the same thing only App is the top level component which holds the function. The state is then updated and passed as a props to both Activity and Rehab which are updated accordingly.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      devices: [],
      data_set: []
    }
  }

  someFunction = (argument)=>{
     this.setState(()=({argument}));
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      Provider store = {
        store
      } >
      <
      Fragment >
      <
      BrowserRouter >
      <
      Switch >
      <
      Route exact path = "/"
      component = {
        Dashboard
      }
      />

      <
      Route exact path = "/rehab"
      render = {
        (props) => < Rehab { ...props
        }
        data_val = {
          this.state.data_set
        }
        someFunction={this.someFunction}
        text = "Shyam Form" / >
      }
      />

      <
      Route exact path = "/activity"
      render = {
        (props) => < Activity { ...props
        }
        data_val = {
          this.state.data_set
        }
        someFunction={this.someFunction}
        text = "Shyam Activity" / >
      }
      /> <
      /Switch> <
      /BrowserRouter> <
      /Fragment> <
      /Provider>
    )
  }
}
const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , wrapper)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped.Even Jamie Dixon's comment helped.